# Symmetric difference of a 3 subset of a finite set X

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B, C, D$ be subsets of a finite set $X$. Prove that $AΔB = CΔD$ if
$AΔC = BΔD$.

I have tried to applied some properties of symmetric difference but all to no avail according to my little knowledge about it. Please, kindly help me out!

Comment: Every element is the inverse of itself under the symmetric difference. Have you taken the symmetric difference with $B\triangle C$ on both sides?

Comment: You have told us what $A,B,C$ are, but not what $D$ is.

Comment: Oh! it was typo error, @GerryMyerson, D also belong to set X.
Thanks in anticipation :)

Comment: The properties you need are commutativity, associativity, for all $A$ $A\Delta A=\phi$, and for all $A$ $A\Delta\phi=A$, where $\phi$ is the empty set. Have a go at it. Or use the hint from @Hanul.

Comment: Alternatively, show that both equalities are equivalent to $A\Delta B\Delta C\Delta D = \emptyset$.

Comment: Making any progress, G'?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, No! I still don't get it,  :(

Comment: OK. Start with $A\Delta B=C\Delta D$. "Multiply" both sides of the equation by $C$, using the properties I listed to make simplifications/rearrangements. Then, multiply both sides by $B$, simplify, rearrange. Then report back on how it's going.

Comment: I say, how's it going?

Comment: Wow it worked perfectly! Thanks so much @GerryMyerson and Hanul Jeon :)

Comment: Good. Now, let me encourage you to write up a solution and post it as an answer.

Comment: ok, I will thanks

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have posted it now, kindly go through it for verification. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof**
suppose $A, B, C, D$ be subsets of a finite set $X$.
we are to prove that $AΔB = CΔD$ if and only if $AΔC = BΔD$.
before we proceed we need some properties as being guided in comment session

- $AΔB = BΔA$ $\longrightarrow$ Cummutative
- $AΔ(BΔC)=(AΔB)ΔC$ $\longrightarrow$ Associative
- $AΔA = \varnothing $
- $AΔ\varnothing = A $

from $AΔB = CΔD$ multiply through by $C$, we have
$\implies AΔBΔC = CΔDΔC$
$\implies AΔBΔC = DΔCΔC = DΔ\varnothing = D$
$\implies AΔBΔC = D$, multiply through by $B$ we have
$\implies AΔBΔCΔB = DΔB = BΔD$
$\implies AΔCΔBΔB = BΔD$
$\implies AΔC = BΔD$

Comment: Good! You should mention associativity, since you use it many times. Also, you have "if" and "only if" the wrong way around.

Comment: notet with thanks, I will edit  it

Comment: @GerryMyerson, kindly check now if it is ok. And the question has been edited too(it suppose to be 'if' not 'iff').
Thanks.